# Consulta con las fechas en Fragment

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, les comento que estoy realizando mi primer fragment en total 5, en el cual estoy empezando a codificar en el firmaulario.java que corresponde, y tengo un problema con la fecha en los fragment en el activity ningún problema, y averiguando hay que realizar una clase la cual la hice y este es el código que utilice:

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    fragment.setListener(listener);
    return fragment;
}

public void setListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);
}

public void show(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, String datePicker) {
}
}
```

este en si no me da problema.
ahora les muestro el código en el java que se realizo.

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.prueba1.R;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class policial extends Fragment {

public policial() {

}

EditText et_unidad,et_constancia,et_parte,et_estamento,et_causa,et_fecha,et_fecha1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_policial, container, false);
    et_unidad = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtunidad);
    et_constancia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtconstancia);
    et_parte = view.findViewById(R.id.txtparte);
    et_estamento = view.findViewById(R.id.txtestamento);
    et_causa = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcausa);
    et_fecha = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechaparte);
    et_fecha1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechacitacion);

    et_fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case et_fecha:
                    showDatePickerDialog();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void showDatePickerDialog() {
            DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                    // +1 because January is zero
                    final String selectedDate = day + " / " + (month+1) + " / " + year;
                    et_fecha.setText(selectedDate);
                }
            });
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

el problema me lo da en la línea del "case et_fecha:" me informa lo siguiente "Incompatible types. Found: 'android.widget.EditText', required: 'int'", no entiendo como cambiarlo a un int, si es un campo de fecha, ojala que me puedan ayudar y asesorar con este problema, busco información a través de la web y traspasarlo de un int a fecha, pero en si este es una date (string) o (varchar)  como se puede hacer noi lo entiendo, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Y ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer en ese `switch`? Lo que te da `view.getId()` es el valor numérico asociado a esa vista. Pulsa en [edit] y explica lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias me equivoque en esa línea debe decir case 1:, pero igual no funciona no me muestra el calendario, con el otro código e funcionaba bien, pero averiguando todos mencionaron que es conveniente realizarlo en un fragment.

Answer (score 0):

el error en el jave del case, se cambia por este.

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.prueba1.R;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class policial extends Fragment {

public policial() {

}

EditText et_unidad,et_constancia,et_parte,et_estamento,et_causa,et_fecha,et_fecha1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_policial, container, false);
    et_unidad = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtunidad);
    et_constancia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtconstancia);
    et_parte = view.findViewById(R.id.txtparte);
    et_estamento = view.findViewById(R.id.txtestamento);
    et_causa = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcausa);
    et_fecha = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechaparte);
    et_fecha1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechacitacion);

    et_fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case 1:
                    showDatePickerDialog();
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void showDatePickerDialog() {
            DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                    final String selectedDate = day + " / " + (month+1) + " / " + year;
                    et_fecha.setText(selectedDate);
                    et_fecha1.requestFocus();
                }
            });
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

pero igual no funciona no me muestra el calendario, les muestro el código que tengo en los activity que me funciona y no me arrojan ningún problema:

```
et_denuncia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    Frmcasos1.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    et_denuncia.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    et_siniestro.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

no sé porque este último no me funciona en los fragment, no lo entiendo, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.